# Glassfish 4 - JDBC Realm

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, jaas, glassfish-4

What's the difference between the Password encryption algorithm and the Digest Algorithm in Glassfish 4?
Because Password encryption algorithm cannot be blank, I used MD5, and for Encoding, Hex.
The Digest Algorithm is blank, so the default is SHA-256.

But if I made a simple login application with JAAS, and create the tables, insert one user, and the password is encrypted with MD5, the user cannot log in. If i encrypt the password with SHA-256, the user can log in.

So, what is the Password encryption algorithm field?

Comment: I am having issue with migration from 4.0 to 4.1.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686737/migration-from-glassfish-4-0-to-glassfish-4-1-1-jdbc-realm-issue

Comment: SHA-256 is only marginally better for a password verifier than MD5, neither should be used. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear on this point, but my interpretation is as follows.  This is based on [Glassfish v4 reference manual](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/reference-manual.pdf).

Password encryption algorithm determines how the passwords are encrypted *within your database*.  This is the parameter `digestrealm-password-enc-algorithm`.  You really want to have this set to something because of course leaving passwords in a database in the clear is a security hole.

When someone tries to authenticate, glassfish needs a way to compare what was submitted to what's in the database.  But, since the latter is all locked up, it needs a key to unlock.  The encryption (strictly, hashing) used on that key is what is defined in Digest Algorithm (parameter `digest-algorithm`).  It defaults to SHA-256 in v4 (prior, it was MD5).

Answer (score 0):

> So, what is the Password encryption algorithm field?

Digest Algorithm is used to encrypt/hash the login request, while Password encryption algorithm is used to decrypt the password from db.

> But if I made a simple login application with JAAS, and create the
>   tables, insert one user, and the password is encrypted with MD5, the
>   user cannot log in.

Put MD5 in password encryption field, and leave Digest Algorithm blank (by default , it is sha-256 in GlassFish 4).

Comment: I did this, but if i want to log in, it isn't working. So what? But if i change the password field to an SHA-256 encoded password, it is working.

Comment: Hi , did you manage to solve it ? Can you put MD5 at both places and try again ? (with MD5 hashed passwords in the database). 

Both Sha-256 and MD5 encryptions are working fine here, with GlassFish OSE 4.0 and MySQL.

Anyway, if it's working with SHA-256 you should stick with that because MD5 hash text has been cracked with just the power of a cluster made of 20 Playstations.. SHA-256 is 'safer' since it takes more time to decrypt it.